# SSIS Converting Percent to Decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssis

I'm trying to get a percentage to display as a decimal in my database.
I have the following set up to convert the percentage columns into decimals:

```
----------------           ----------------           ------------
excel source     ---------> data conversion ----------> db output
----------------           ----------------           ------------
```

I've tried to strictly convert the input to decimal and numeric.
Neither of these have changed my results.

In my columns in the database I'm getting just 0's and 1's.

Forgive my crude drawing; I do not have enough rep to post pictures yet.

Comment: also: convert the *INPUT* not image

Comment: Can you show how you are doing the "data conversion" along with sample input and output for a few rows

Comment: you can edit your question and correct mistakes. edit button is under the tags

Comment: Also, specifically, what does SSIS think the data types are for the percentage columns in the Excel source?

Comment: The source excel file has the percentages formatted as percentages.
I cannot show anything since my reputation isn't 15 yet.
The database design has the columns for percentages as int. <-- I think that may be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for

Excel sheet like this is the source.

[image]

I just tested it in my system.It is working fine. This is what I did.

1. Created an SSIS package with just 1 DFT.
2. Data flow is given below. Please note that the value which appeared as 40% in Excel sheet is visible as 0.40. So I added two derived columns. One converting as such and the next which multiplies with 100.

[image]

the derived column structure is shown below.

[image]

The destination table structure be

```
Create table Destination
(
id int,
name varchar(15),
hike decimal(8,2)
)
```

I am getting the result as expected.

```
Select * from Destination
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for! This worked so well thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this. Here's one:

1) Save your excel file as a tab delimited text file.

2) Create a New Flat File Connection in SSIS
   a) Set File Name = .txt file
   b) Go to Advanced tab and click on the column with the percentages
   c) Set the Data Type to match the target field in your database (e.g., numeric(10,5)

3) In the SSIS workflow, create a derived column of your percent field to convert from percent to decimal(e.g., newfield = oldfield/100). *Make sure to check the data type has not changed in the Derived Column Transformation Editor.*

Comment: I will totally give this a shot! Thanks!