# Converting #% to #.## format

Tags: excel, ssis, excel-formula, expression, data-conversion

Let me start off with, I am new at this, so bear with me. 
I am pulling data in from an excel file and I need an expression that can look at one of my rows that has both decimals and percentages in it. I need them to be uniform and just have decimal format. So basically, some of fields have either 5% (shown with the % sign) and others have .05. I need all of my output to have the .05 type. I have been trying to figure this out for hours and am at a loss.
Currently I am using `(DT_DECIMAL,6)REPLACE(TRIM([Percentage Off]),"%","")` but that seems to just be stripping the percentage sign off and it doesn't convert the number to a percentage. Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be asking what you can do from an SSIS perspective but if this was my task I would simply change the number format in Excel for that column to `0.00##` or something appropriate. I'm also curious as to why SSIS even thinks there is a difference unless both the numeric and percentage values are being interpreted as text.

Answer (score 0):

The set of links below will likely get you to the answer.
Note that you **may** need only a *CAST*, not a *REPLACE*.
I do not have a system at hand where to test this, but I expect it to be useful (if not providing the explicit answer) for you.

1. **[Cast (SSIS Expression)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141704.aspx)**.
   Syntax:

   `(type_spec) expression`
2. **[REPLACE (SSIS Expression)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141196.aspx)**.
   Syntax:

   `REPLACE(character_expression,searchstring,replacementstring)`
3. **[? : (Conditional) (SSIS Expression)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141680.aspx)**.
   Syntax:

   `boolean_expression?expression1:expression2`
4. **[Operators (SSIS Expression)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137538.aspx)**.
5. **[SSIS Converting Percent to Decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768482/ssis-converting-percent-to-decimal)**.